# Read file from Amazon S3 with nodeJS and post it to another server with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, axios, aws-sdk

Im trying to read a file (image) from amazon S3 and post it to another server with `multipart/form`.

```
  let imageParams = { Bucket: 'my-bucket', Key: 'imageName.jpg' };

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', s3.getObject(imageParams).createReadStream());

  let apiResponse = await api.post("/fileUpload", formData,
    { params: { token: process.env.API_TOKEN } }, 
    { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } } );
```

But im not managing it to work, it returns me:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 415
```

maybe im misunderstanding how the `createReadStream()` works?

Comment: what are you using for api? basically what is powering `fileUpload` endpoint?

Comment: Its not my API, and when i try to upload the file with postman it works just fine...

Comment: Have you tried removing the multipart header because I am able to run your code without any issue to a mock api.

Comment: If you mean the api.post it is axios.

module.exports.api = axios.default.create({
    baseURL: ' https://my.api.com',
});

Comment: already tried, it returns me the same error :/

Comment: I've also tried to save the file into the server and just read it.
like:
formData.append('image', fs.createReadStream('imageName.jpg'));

Answer (score 0):

Use concat for pipe the stream. Otherwise form data send only the first chunk of stream, and the server don't know how to handle it.

For example

```
const axios = require('axios');
const {S3} = require('aws-sdk');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const s3 = new S3();
var concat = require('concat-stream')

const api = axios.default.create({
    baseURL: 'http://example.com',

})

const readStream = s3.getObject({Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'file'}).createReadStream();
readStream.pipe(concat(filebuffer => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', filebuffer);
    formData.getLength((err, length) => {
        console.log(length)
        const headers = formData.getHeaders({'content-length': length})
        console.log({headers})
        return api({
            method: 'post',
            url: "/upload",
            headers: headers,
            data: formData
        })
    })

}))
```

Comment: It returned me 500 should i set the params like this?

return API({
  method: 'post',
  url: "/upload",
  headers: headers,
  params: { id: ticketId, token: process.env.API_TOKEN },
  data: formData
})

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 500
      at createError (C:\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (C:\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
      at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:236:11)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
      at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

Comment: It works with postman. 

I have 3 query parameters: token, id, and actionId.

A value in the header as : Content-type : multipart/form-data, and the body is form-data with only one value that is the file.

Comment: Yes, set the params. The call stack you attach is call stack of axios not from server.
The error from server is in data property of error.